# isRunning returns NO even though AVCaptureSession is running

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I am capturing video with AVCaptureSession, and everything is working just fine on iOS 6.1. However, I have been trying to check from another thread whether my capture session is running via isRunning method. However, the method returns NO regardless of whether my capture session is running or not.

However, if I called isRunning method on the main thread; I get the correct value.

Does anyone have a good explanation for this?

Comment: Can you show us the code you are using to check the thread? Also, maybe you have a particular reason for it, but why not adopt the <AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate> protocol and implement -(void) captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection. And put some nslog inthere. One other place you can look into is instruments by thread and you will see that thread.

Answer (score 0):

My bad. It turns out that the way I was accessing my capture session was not thread safe. Also it is worth pointing out that running( with "isRunning" method as a getter) is a non-atomic property, which does not help with the whole problem either.

Comment: Sorry to bring this up many, many years later. I'm finding myself in some cases where the isRunning prop returns NO / 0 even though the session is indeed running. Minimizing and opening the app again seems to properly update it.

Comment: Really looks like an iOS bug. This happens when the session is interrupted due to a phone call, but then resumed. The session resumed event is fired before the interruption and never again. I would guess this is where the variable gets screwed up.